# Word frequency counter

Tags: javascript, counter, frequency, cpu-word

from the below code

```
var words = 'one two three four one two three';
wordArray = words.split(' ');
var newArray = [];
var words = {};

$.each(wordArray, function (ix, word ) {
    if ($.inArray(word , newArray) > -1) {
        words[word]++;
    }
    else {
        console.log('that wasnt in the array');
        words[word] = 1;
    }

});
```

how to get a descending output of word frequency sorted by word-count? Thanks

Comment: Use the counter in `words` to sort the `wordArray` array. You *do* know [how to sort an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)?

Comment: Why are you using jQuery when POJS has more efficient methods?

Comment: You're testing against newArray but you never put any values in newArray.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var wordsString = 'one two three four one two three';
var wordArray = wordsString.split(' ');
var wordCounter = {};

for (var i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
  if (wordCounter[wordArray[i]]) {
    wordCounter[wordArray[i]] += 1;
  } else {
    wordCounter[wordArray[i]] = 1;
  }
}

console.log(wordCounter)
```

At this point we have total number of each "word", but don't have sorting.
To add sorting, we simply sort wordArray using [Array.sort()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) function:

```
var wordArraySortFunction = function(word1, word2){
    if(wordCounter[word1] < wordCounter[word2]){
        return -1;
    }else if(wordCounter[word1] == wordCounter[word2]){
        return 0;
    }else if(wordCounter[word1] > wordCounter[word2]){
        return 1;
    }
}

wordArray.sort(wordArraySortFunction);
```

if you want to reverse sorting order, you could either rewrite sorting function:

```
var wordArraySortFunction = function(word1, word2){
    if(wordCounter[word1] < wordCounter[word2]){
        return 1;
    }else if(wordCounter[word1] == wordCounter[word2]){
        return 0;
    }else if(wordCounter[word1] > wordCounter[word2]){
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Or you could use [Array.reverse()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp) on sorted array:

```
wordArray.reverse();
```

Now as we have sorted words according to their frequencies, we can output them:

```
for(var i=0; i<wordArray.length; i++){
    console.log(wordArray[i] + ': ' + wordCounter[wordArray[i]]);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var wordsString = 'one two three four one two three';
var wordArray = words.split(' ');
var words = {};

$.each(wordArray, function (i, word ) {
    if (word in words) {
        words[word] += 1 ;
    }
    else {
        console.log('that wasnt in the array');
        words[word] = 1;
    }

});
```